# Эмуляция взаимодействия с пользователем через bat

Tags: java, консоль, bat, jar, ввод

Суть проблемы:
Есть jar программы, которую нужно перезапускать раз в час. 
Чтобы ее запустить, нужно в консольном меню ввести сначала цифру 1 и нажать Enter, потом ввести порт, на котором должна стартануть программа и нажать Enter.

я пробовал через пайп передавать echo 1 и пробовал конструкцию

```
java -jar jar.jar < nul set /p str="1"
```

но это никак не помогло.

Есть ли способ сделать это из bat либо любыми другими средствами?

Comment: используйте nircmd.exe

Comment: а что делает программа?

Comment: предложение номер 1 - доработать программу для запуска без ввода с клавиатуры

Comment: Сначала надо писать в консоль, а потом читать из неё , а не наоборот.

Comment: @Dred, интересная вещь, но я не нашел ничего из ее возможностей, что могло бы мне помочь. Можете подсказать?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, если бы была возможность доработать, было бы здорово... Программа является консольным симулятором smpp-сервера.

Comment: @ДанилМанмарёв можно попробовать ее декомпилировать и посмотреть как она устроена.. велика вероятность что достаточно добавить один свой класс, использующий исходный jar как зависимость

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл `param.txt` со следующим содержимым:

```
1
1234
```

`1234` это номер порта.

Запустите так: `java -jar jar.jar < param.txt`.

Comment: это не помогло, теперь бесконечно выводится меню)

Comment: Возможно программа которую вы используете не читает из входного потока, а напрямую обращается к консоли. В этом случае нет простого способа передать ей что-нибудь. Поищите в документации, может оно принемает параметры или читает конфиги.

Comment: увы, ни аргументов, ни конфига.

Comment: Попробуйте декомпилировать и посмотреть что там внутри.

Answer (score 0):

Качаете nircmd.exe [отсюда](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#using)
создаете скриптовый файл
В него помещаете код, например,

```
cmdwait 2000 sendkey enter press 
sendkey 1 press
sendkey enter press 
cmdwait 2000 sendkey enter press 
sendkey 8080 press
sendkey enter press
```

В моем случае, я поместил nircmd.exe и файл msg.ncl по пути **C:\nircmd**
Команда запуска будет выглядеть так

```
C:\nircmd>nircmd.exe script msg.ncl
```

В итоге, у вас произойдет запуск скрипта, подождет 2 секунды и нажмет 1, потом подождет еще 2 секунды, нажмет еще , допустим порт 8080 и нажмется интер. Теоретически, может вам хватит только этих строк.

```
sendkey 1 press
cmdwait 2000 sendkey 8080 press
```

У меня не было возможности протестировать локально, так как я не знаю какой код у вас принимает эти команды.

Через стандартный планировщик Windows делаете запуск команды

```
 C:\nircmd>nircmd.exe script msg.ncl
```

раз в час. Всё.

Почитайте инструкции на странице, где качать саму программу. Может вам еще что-то интересным и полезным покажется.

Comment: вот так и рождаются монстры обмотанные скотчем и проволокой, лишь бы работало

Comment: Ну да) Но если нет возможности исправить. У меня было необходимо, запускать каждый день софт, который запускает  прожекторы, а вечером их отключать. Софт от сторонней компании. Так вот, с помощью nircmd, софт открывался, разворачивался на весь экран и эмулировал нажатии мыши в разных координатах, где были клавиши включения прожекторов и запуска разных "программ" работы прожекторов) Это, чтобы самостоятельно каждый раз не заходить на удаленный комп, который только этим и занимается.